# How to turn a dictionary written to a .txt file, into an actual dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a .txt file (test.txt) with an example dictionary written in it

```
{"1": "John", "2": "Jeremy", "3": "Jake"}
```

In python I'm trying to grab the dictionary from this text file, and use it as a dictionary in my program, but the class of the variable isn't a dictionary, it's the 'str' class.

```
dictionary = open("test.txt", mode="r")
print(dictionary)
print(type(dictionary)

Output:
{"1": "John", "2": "Jeremy", "3": "Jake"}
<class 'str'>
```

Just want to know how I can make this variable a dictionary instead of a string

Thanks

Comment: If the keys are always strings you could use `json.load`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a number of assumptions.

First, `dictionary` in your code is a file, not a string.  You forgot the `read`.  Second, the data in your file is NOT a valid dictionary.  The names need to be quoted.

Assuming they are quoted, what you have is JSON.  Use `json.load`:

Contents:

```
{ "1": "John", "2": "Jeremy", "3": "Jake" }
```

Code:

```
import json
dictionary = json.load(open('test.txt'))
```

Comment: the non-quoted names were a mistake when I was writing the question since it was a made up example dictionary, but thank you

Comment: This shows how important an accurate question is.  Many of us tried to run your code to provide an answer, but your code was nonsense and your example data was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't convert this string to a dictionary as its format isn't correct, it should be like this

```
dictionary = '{"1": "John", "2": "Jeremy", "3": "Jake"}'
```

notice how I added the names between the ""

For the conversion you will use json library

Full Code:

```
import json

dictionary = open("test.txt", mode="r").read()

conv = json.loads(dictionary)

print(conv)
print(type(conv))
```

This is the code I tested with:

```
import json

str = '{"1": "John", "2": "Jeremy", "3": "Jake"}'

conv = json.loads(str)

print(conv)
print(type(conv))
```

My might not work if you don't fix your .txt file.

Comment: the non-quoted names were a mistake when I was writing the question since it was a made up example dictionary.  thank you